# ListView in my Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-activity, android-listview

I have attemmpted to make a.    ListView.   But it won't work. I click this button in the main activity and it crashed.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Coming Soon: Expansion View"
    android:onClick="exp"
    />
```

Here is the Main Activity JAVA code. All it is is simple main menu stuff for my game I'm developing. This is madness.

```
 package com.apw.games.rpg.medieval;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.graphics.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new 
    AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Medieval: The Video Game");
    alertDialog.setMessage("All Games Begin. Season One of the Game, Version 1. First Expansion coming soon- Life of Darkness.");
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//here you can add functions

            } });
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.medieval_background);
    alertDialog.show();
}



@Override
public void exp(View v) {
    Intent 
        intt = new Intent(this, Expansions.class);
    startActivity(intt);
}


@Override 
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

 }
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); 
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); return true; }

@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
// Handle item selection 
switch (item.getItemId()) { 


    case R.id.quit: 
    Intent intent =  new Intent(this, Exit.class); 
    startActivity(intent); 
    return true; 
    case R.id.new_game: 
        Intent i = new Intent(this, New_Game.class); 
        startActivity(i); 
        return true; 
    case R.id.visit_site: 
        Intent inte = new Intent(this, Site.class); 
        startActivity(inte); 
        return true; 
    case R.id.apw_site: 
        Intent inten = new Intent(this, APWSite.class); 
        startActivity(inten); 
        return true; 

    default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }}}
```

Here is the layout stuff from the listview. Also, all this is from a tutotial I got from someone on the StackOverflow, so just to let you know. This first one is called simplerow.xml

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Now here is the other one called expansions.xml. The java code used through these "R.layout" files will be posted afterwords.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now here's the "grand slam" Java file that I'm not sure what is going on because, to add on to this, I'm doing this all from Android, just so you know. My AIDE said no errors but when I start the app and I click the button in the Main Activity, it crashes. I wasn't sure whether it was an onClick issue or whatnot.

```
 package com.apw.games.rpg.medieval;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.apw.games.rpg.medieval.*;

public class Expansions extends Activity {

  private ListView mainListView ;
  private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.expansions);

    // Find the ListView resource. 
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list_view );

    // Create and populate a List of planet names.
    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
                                  "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};  
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );


    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);

    // Add more planets. If you passed a String[] instead of a List<String> 
    // into the ArrayAdapter constructor, you must not add more items. 
    // Otherwise an exception will occur.
    listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );
    listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );
    listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );
    listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );
    listAdapter.add( "Eris" );

    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );      
  }
}
```

If possible, please tell me where my error was and please help me correct it.

Comment: Did you register `Expansions` Activity in your manifest?

Comment: @Vishal Vyas yes I did thnxs 4 cking though

Comment: Yah I made sure i had it declared.

Comment: You may be getting some exception like `ERROR/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException:` so please provide us with full stack trace.

Comment: Okay hold on I will have it in real quick

Answer (score 0):

use this for xml layout:

```
       <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap content" />
```

following code:

```
        public static String selected = "";
         private static final String[] RATINGS = new String[] {
    "1","2","3","4","5"
};

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView1);

          list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, RATINGS));
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            selected = RATINGS[arg2];               
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, planetList);
```

You are telling the adapter which layout to use, but not which element in the layout to map the data to.  Since you are using a custom TextView name, you need to tell the adapter that.

Using the constructor you are trying to use makes the adapter look for a default TextView id of `text1`.

So, you have a choice.  You can use a different contructor that gives both the resource file and the TextView id.

If you do, it should look something like this:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView, planetList);
```

Or, you can change the id of your TextView to `text1` and leave your call to the adapter just as it is.

See the [ArrayAdapter docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter) for a list of all the various constructors you can use to call the adapter.